# Installation of wso2 application server 5.3.0

Tags: java-8, wso2, wso2-as

I am trying to install wso2 application server version 5.3.0. Jdk version 1.8.0_102. But I am getting "Error: Could not find or load main class 2\Web"

[image]

I have tried installing wso2as 2.5.1 also along with JDK 1.8.0_72 as described in my university guidelines. still, the error persists. please help me with this error of class 2\web.

OS in use: Windows 10 Education

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: put your installation to path without spaces e. g. e:\Study\wso2\wso2is (please note some functionalities have problems with long file path names, try to keep it moderate too)

Comment: thank you so much @gusto2 ... It was the silliest mistake from my side... that 2/web is part of folder address term 2/web application architecture.